# Getting a posts tags using SQL joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I'm trying to retrieve the tags of each blog post in one SQL query. I have a `posts` table, `post_tags` table and a `tags` table. The `post_tags` table exists to remove the many-to-many relationship between posts and tags. Here's the schema for those tables:

```
| p_id | c_id | u_id |   title   |     body    |      published      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  1   |   1  | first post| lorem ipsum | 2012-01-27 18:37:47 |


| p_id | t_id |
---------------
|  1   |  3   |


| t_id |     name    |     slug    |
------------------------------------
|  3   | programming | programming |
```

And the PHP method I'm using:

```
public function getLatestPosts()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT title, clean_title, body, published, name, slug
                               FROM posts
                               LEFT JOIN post_tags ON posts.p_id=post_tags.p_id
                               LEFT JOIN tags ON post_tags.t_id=tags.t_id
                               ORDER BY published DESC');
    $posts = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $posts[] = array('title' => $row->title,
                             'clean_title' => $row->clean_title,
                             'body' => $row->body,
                             'published' => $row->published,
                             'tags' => array('name' => $row->name,
                                             'slug' => $row->slug));
    }
    print_r($posts);
    return $posts;
}
```

It kinda works, the posts tags are being retrieved for each post, but I have duplicate posts. Here's a `print_r` dump of the results of the query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Second blog post, this is a pretty long title
            [clean_title] => second-blog-post-this-is-a-pretty-long-title
            [body] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget est sit amet libero volutpat eleifend facilisis sollicitudin nisl. Nulla elit eros, semper eget tincidunt quis, egestas a nisl. Duis tempor tempus sapien consequat pellentesque. Cras vitae orci risus. Duis urna velit, interdum ac consectetur nec, condimentum non tellus. Sed nec nibh nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras purus nulla, tincidunt quis placerat a, interdum at turpis. Pellentesque in lectus lacus. Sed at venenatis neque.
            [published] => 2012-01-27 20:15:52
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [slug] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first post!
            [clean_title] => this-is-my-first-post
            [body] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget est sit amet libero volutpat eleifend facilisis sollicitudin nisl. Nulla elit eros, semper eget tincidunt quis, egestas a nisl. Duis tempor tempus sapien consequat pellentesque. Cras vitae orci risus. Duis urna velit, interdum ac consectetur nec, condimentum non tellus. Sed nec nibh nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras purus nulla, tincidunt quis placerat a, interdum at turpis. Pellentesque in lectus lacus. Sed at venenatis neque.
            [published] => 2012-01-27 18:37:47
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [name] => programming
                    [slug] => programming
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first post!
            [clean_title] => this-is-my-first-post
            [body] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget est sit amet libero volutpat eleifend facilisis sollicitudin nisl. Nulla elit eros, semper eget tincidunt quis, egestas a nisl. Duis tempor tempus sapien consequat pellentesque. Cras vitae orci risus. Duis urna velit, interdum ac consectetur nec, condimentum non tellus. Sed nec nibh nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras purus nulla, tincidunt quis placerat a, interdum at turpis. Pellentesque in lectus lacus. Sed at venenatis neque.
            [published] => 2012-01-27 18:37:47
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [name] => android
                    [slug] => android
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => This is my first post!
            [clean_title] => this-is-my-first-post
            [body] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget est sit amet libero volutpat eleifend facilisis sollicitudin nisl. Nulla elit eros, semper eget tincidunt quis, egestas a nisl. Duis tempor tempus sapien consequat pellentesque. Cras vitae orci risus. Duis urna velit, interdum ac consectetur nec, condimentum non tellus. Sed nec nibh nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras purus nulla, tincidunt quis placerat a, interdum at turpis. Pellentesque in lectus lacus. Sed at venenatis neque.
            [published] => 2012-01-27 18:37:47
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [name] => windows
                    [slug] => windows
                )

        )

)
```

As I see it, instead of returning each tag for the post, it's returning more than one of that post just with different tags. I need it so that the `tags` array for each post has an element for each tag of that post.

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047168/retrieving-tags-based-on-post-id/9047351#9047351

Check my answer there to get what you're wanting.  I mentioned duplicate rows would happen with the answered solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter** your data at the PHP level after you have retrieved it from SQL:

```
public function getLatestPosts()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT p_id, title, clean_title, body, published, name, slug
                               FROM posts
                               LEFT JOIN post_tags ON posts.p_id=post_tags.p_id
                               LEFT JOIN tags ON post_tags.t_id=tags.t_id
                               ORDER BY published DESC');
    $posts = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        if (!isset($posts[$row->p_id])) {
            $posts[$row->p_id] = array('title' => $row->title,
                                       'clean_title' => $row->clean_title,
                                       'body' => $row->body,
                                       'published' => $row->published,
                                       'tags' => array());
        }
        $posts[$row->p_id]['tags'][] = array('name' => $row->name,
                                             'slug' => $row->slug);
    }
    print_r($posts);
    return $posts;
}
```